# Autosave: How to prevent it being re-enabled with each new session

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2016

I find the Autosave feature to be very intrusive and it also interferes with some macros I run.  I know how to disable it via File/Options/Save/untick the box, but even if I then immediately save my file the feature is re-enabled the next time I open the file, so I have to manually disable it again.

How can I either turn it off permanently (for this file only) or disable it via VBA?

Thanks

Eric

Comment: AS an FYI, whenever you save in MS Project you remove the undo history. For this reason I don't use it.

Comment: Agreed, that is annoying, but unfortunately I am stuck with MSP.

Comment: I should clarify, its autosave that i don't use. I too am stuck with MSP...

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that my IT dept have updated my registry which I am unfortunately not able to edit.  This link

https://getadmx.com/?Category=Office2016&Policy=proj16.Office.Microsoft.Policies.Windows::L_PjSaveEvery

shows what needs to be changed, and explains why it resets each time I close and reopen Project.

[image]